# Change item row by row in python dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column based on the presence of a certain word in a column of strings. In my example I want to create a new column `state` if a manually specified `state` is present in a column.

i.e. if the column has the word `Kedah` then it will create a new column that is `state` and the value is `Kedah`.
example:

Kampung Baling, Kedah

then column state just take 'Kedah'

My dataframe looks like this

```
0   2111    sementa, Selangor
1   2134    Tuaran, Sabah
2   2876    Klang, Selangor
```

`pd.DataFrame([[2111, 'sementa, Selangor'], [2134, 'Tuaran, Sabah'], [2876, 'Klang, Selangor']], columns=['id', 'makan'])`

My intended output is

```
0   2111    sementa, Selangor   Selangor
1   2134    Tuaran, Sabah   Sabah
2   2876    Klang, Selangor     Selangor
```

I tried the following:

```
for i in dfexp['makan']:
    if 'Selangor' or 'selangor' in i:
        dfexp['State'] = 'Selangor'
    elif 'Sabah' or 'sabah' in i:
        dfexp['State'] = 'Sabah'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, appreciate the advise you gave to me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each state you can check if any of the rows of the **makan** column contains a state by using `pandas.DataFrame.str.contains()`. Then you can set the value of the `State` column to a state of your liking.

Here an example for one of the states:

```
df.loc[lambda x: x['makan'].str.contains('Selangor|selangor'), 'State'] = 'Selangor'
```